# Почему я получаю не полный список в ответе requests

Tags: python

Вот мой код:

```
import requests


player_name = 'floppa_b'
player_id = None
game_id = "csgo"
api_header = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee',
                           "content-type": "application/json"}



player_id_request = requests.get(f"https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/players?nickname=" + player_name + "&game=CSGO",headers=api_header)
player_id_data = player_id_request.json()
player_id = player_id_data["player_id"]

player_history_request = requests.get(f"https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/players/{player_id}/history?game=CSGO", headers=api_header)

print(player_history_request.text)
```

по идее я должен получить:

```
{
  "end": 0,
  "from": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "competition_id": "string",
      "competition_name": "string",
      "competition_type": "string",
      "faceit_url": "string",
      "finished_at": 0,
      "game_id": "string",
      "game_mode": "string",
      "match_id": "string",
      "match_type": "string",
      "max_players": 0,
      "organizer_id": "string",
      "playing_players": [
        "string"
      ],
      "region": "string",
      "results": {
        "score": {
          "additionalProp1": 0,
          "additionalProp2": 0,
          "additionalProp3": 0
        },
        "winner": "string"
      },
      "started_at": 0,
      "status": "string",
      "teams": {
        "additionalProp1": {
          "avatar": "string",
          "nickname": "string",
          "players": [
            {
              "avatar": "string",
              "faceit_url": "string",
              "game_player_id": "string",
              "game_player_name": "string",
              "nickname": "string",
              "player_id": "string",
              "skill_level": 0
            }
          ],
          "team_id": "string",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "additionalProp2": {
          "avatar": "string",
          "nickname": "string",
          "players": [
            {
              "avatar": "string",
              "faceit_url": "string",
              "game_player_id": "string",
              "game_player_name": "string",
              "nickname": "string",
              "player_id": "string",
              "skill_level": 0
            }
          ],
          "team_id": "string",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "additionalProp3": {
          "avatar": "string",
          "nickname": "string",
          "players": [
            {
              "avatar": "string",
              "faceit_url": "string",
              "game_player_id": "string",
              "game_player_name": "string",
              "nickname": "string",
              "player_id": "string",
              "skill_level": 0
            }
          ],
          "team_id": "string",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "teams_size": 0
    }
  ],
  "start": 0,
  "to": 0
}
```

Но получаю лишь

```
{"items":[],"start":0,"end":20,"from":0,"to":1681541935}
```

Почему так происходит? Как получить полный ответ?

Comment: Просто напишите `history?game=csgo` (название игры маленькими буквами)